# (RESOLVED) Include FontAwesome in a Vue 3 library built with Vite 5

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, font-awesome

I'm creating my own components library with Vue 3, built with Vite 5. I succeeded in building it then using it in other projects, but I have troubles with FontAwesome.
I want my components to use FontAwesome icons, and it does work if I launch the project using `vite` command. BUT when I build my library then import it in another project, I have the following error in my browser:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: font-awesome-icon
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

Here is how I use FontAwesome in the library:

- `main.ts`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import './assets/styles/main.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { faChevronDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

library.add(faChevronDown);

const app = createApp(App);
app.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
app.mount('#app');
```

- `Dropdown.vue`

```
<-- some code here !-->
        <span>
          <font-awesome-icon icon='fa-solid fa-chevron-down' />
        </span>
<-- some code here !-->
```

And here's my `vite.config.ts` for the library:

```
import { resolve } from 'node:path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [Vue({ style: { filename: 'style.css' } })],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
        @use "./src/assets/styles/styles.scss";
        @import './src/assets/styles/vars';
        `,
      },
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: './dist',
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'my-lib-name',
      formats: ['es'],
      fileName: (format) => `${'my-lib-name'}.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        globals: { vue: 'Vue' },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [{
      find: 'public',
      replacement: resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    }],
  },
});
```

I tried to find a solution, like using `optimizeDeps` Vite option to include FontAwesome dependencies or installing these packages manually in the host project, but nothing seems to be ok.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

**EDIT (23 feb. 2024):** I tried something based on the solution given in comments below -> I let FontAwesome packages as dependencies then it's automatically installed when someone include my library in a project, and I moved the `library.add(...)` part in my library components so that each component is responsible for importing the icons it needs. This way, users of my library will only have to add `app.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);` in the `main.ts` of their project.
Thanks to [José Ramirez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13886104/jos%C3%A9-ram%C3%ADrez) for helping me!

Comment: The recommended approach is to specify the fontawesome package as a peer dependency of the package and instruct the consumer of your library to install it as well.  This allows the most freedom for consumers.

Comment: True, but it also requires additional configuration for consumers, + manually adding each icon in their project like I did in `main.ts`, which is exactly I don't want to do because it can be really exhausting as a user!

Comment: You might be misunderstanding:  They install your package, then they install the fontawesome package.  You did the heavy lifting in your main.ts.  Consumers consume your main.ts.

Comment: I tried the thing by installing my library on another project + the dependencies, and I had to configure the `main.ts` of this other project by adding FontAwesomeIcon + the icons I need, which is not really what I want